# Erlang: how to profile whether qlc:q does full table scan, key prefix scan or key lookup?

Tags: erlang, profiling

How to profile whether qlc:q does full table scan, key prefix scan or key lookup?

For instance, ets of type set with entries like {{KeyPrefix, KeySuffix}, Value} - will

```
qlc:q([
    {{KeyPrefix, KeySuffix}, Value} ||
    {{KeyPrefix, KeySuffix}, Value} <- ets:table(Table),
    KeyPrefix =:= Something
])
```

do full table scan or key prefix scan?

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain a lot of informations about your QLC expression using [qlc:info/1](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/qlc.html#info-1). That may not help you determine whether a given subquery uses a full table scan or whatnot but that does give you back the query plan and the tables related to your query, which you can then pass to [ets:info/1](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html#info-1) to retrieve their type and keypos.

Answer (score 0):

ETS is not implemented in Erlang, it is implemented in the runtime system (presumably in C ?).  As such I don't believe it is possible to do that today.  Even if you figured out a way to do it, your method could break when you upgraded to a new release of Erlang.  A reliable method would require the runtime system to expose some kind of introspection API to the guts of ETS, and I think that's unlikely to happen so long as it is not implemented in Erlang.  Of course you could dig around in the code to get a better idea of what might happen in a given scenario, but I suspect your time would be better spent focusing on your application code.

Comment: This question isn't specific to ETS, I don't think. He could foreseeably implement the same QLC on an mnesia table or on an Erlang tuple-list, and the same question would still apply.

Answer (score 0):

In our experience, sometimes a `qlc` eval (via list comprehension) is very smart, and sometimes it is very dumb. That is to say, I think your question is valid.

I know of no way to do precisely what you want, but you may be able to get this info via other means. You can certainly look at the source code of the `qlc` module to see if you can glean any insight from that. Further, you could insert some debug statements inside the `qlc` functions and recompile your Erlang runtime to get some more feedback.

Good luck

-tjw